# i have CORS Error in socket.io (Node.js) when i want ot connect to that

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cors

I have a socket.io service that different devices want to connect to that, and because of it, it's very important to me that my socket.io service allows all origins (even when a client doesn't set any origin in the header) to connect to that, this is my io (server-side):

```
const server = http.createServer(app); // app is express app
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
    allowEIO3: true,
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true
    },
});
```

and this is my client:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:4855/', {
  timeout: 60 * 1000,
  reconnection: true,
  forceNew: true, 
  query: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  // extraHeaders: {
  //   Authorization: "ksi",
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  // },
  // Headers: {
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": 'http://localhost',
  // },
  // headers: {
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  // }
});
socket.connect();
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: "even when a client doesn't set any origin in the header" — If the client doesn't include an origin in the header it either (a) isn't a browser so doesn't enforce the same origin policy (b) is making a same origin request so the same origin policy doesn't apply or (c) is refusing to use CORS and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

And you said:

> ```
> origin: '*',
> ```

So you have to return the actual origin and not the wildcard.

The [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/) says:

> All options will be forwarded to the cors package. The complete list of options can be found here.

Which, in turn, [says](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options):

> origin: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header.
> Possible values:
>
> - Boolean - set origin to true to reflect the request origin, as defined by req.header('Origin'), or set it to false to disable CORS.
> - String - set origin to a specific origin. For example if you set it to "http://example.com" only requests from "http://example.com" will
>   be allowed.
> - RegExp - set origin to a regular expression pattern which will be used to test the request origin. If it's a match, the request origin
>   will be reflected. For example the pattern /example.com$/ will
>   reflect any request that is coming from an origin ending with
>   "example.com".
> - Array - set origin to an array of valid origins. Each origin can be a String or a RegExp. For example ["http://example1.com",
>   /.example2.com$/] will accept any request from "http://example1.com"
>   or from a subdomain of "example2.com".
> - Function - set origin to a function implementing some custom logic. The function takes the request origin as the first parameter and a
>   callback (called as callback(err, origin), where origin is a
>   non-function value of the origin option) as the second.

Since you want to allow *any origin*, you can't use a string or an array.

The other options would all work, but the simplest is the boolean.

```
cors: {
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
},
```

Comment: Allowing credentials with arbitrary origins is terrible security advice. If the server in question uses cookies as an alternative to Bearer authentication, users' data will be at risk.

Comment: @jub0bs What would be a secure solution when we need mobile apps connected to the socket.io server?

Comment: @Pierre Specify a limited number of allowed origins, or don't rely on cookie-based authentication.

Comment: Thanks, I use JWT for authorization so I suppose that should be fine enough

Answer (score 1):

If your backend relies on the Bearer authentication scheme (as your code snippet suggests) and not on cookies, you do *not* need to use [credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) or to [allow credentials in your CORS configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials). You can keep using the wildcard (`*`) to specify the allowed origins; you'll also need to explicitly allow the `Authorization` request header:

```js
cors: {
  origin: '*',
  allowedHeaders: ["authorization"]
}
```

[This instance of Jake Archibald's playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&requestSendCredentials=&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=*&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=&preflightAllowHeaders=Authorization&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=*&responseAllowCredentials=&responseExposeHeaders=&requestHeaderName=Authorization&requestHeaderValue=xxx) may be enough to convince you.

The CORS configuration above is secure insofar as cross-origin attackers cannot forge authenticated requests on behalf of their victims.

---

If, on the other hand, your backend server relies on cookies, you need to use credentialed requests and allow credentials in your CORS configuration. However, the CORS spec [forbids the use of the wildcard in conjunction with credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials). It may be tempting to allow all origins with credentials ([as recommended by Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72958401/2541573)), but that amounts to voiding the protection provided by the Same-Origin Policy and exposes your users to cross-origin attacks. More details in [James Kettle's post on Portswigger's website](https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties).